# Tokio.rs based I2C interface for sensor

Tags: linux, rust, sensors, i2c, rust-tokio

I have been reading up on [Tokio.rs](https://tokio.rs/) for doing async IO and it seems a good fit for modelling a [Stream](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.11/futures/stream/index.html) of sensor values. However, Tokio is complex and I don't quite understand how I would interface I2C sensor reading with Tokio.

My concrete task is to implement support for [MPU9250](https://store.invensense.com/datasheets/invensense/MPU9250REV1.0.pdf) on the [BeagleBone Blue](http://beagleboard.org/blue) where I would like to utilize Tokio for the number of combinators that would make interfacing easier (having the ability to join streams of sensor data ensuring that they arrive at the same time is one advantage I see straight away).

The most straight forward way I can see is to use [Tokio-Timer](https://docs.rs/tokio-timer/0.1.0/tokio_timer/) setting up an interval and read sensor values when the timer fires. Is this a good design or are there better ways of doing this? I should also mention that I need other sensors connected so a general method is preferred.